# How to disable past dates from today's date in calendar controle?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a bootstrap calendar control and I am unable to disable the past dates from today's date. Please help to solve it. My control is

```
<div class="span6"> 
     <div class="input-append date date-picker" id="datetimepicker" data-date-viewmode="years" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date="today">                                                        
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" placeholder=" Select Sem Start Date" CssClass="large m-wrap"/> 
      <span class="add-on" style="display: none;"> </span>
      </div>
      <asp:Label ID="lbldatecompare" runat="server" Text="Not allowed select past date" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server" Text="" /> 
</div>
```

I tried the following function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {

       $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ minDate: new Date() });
   });
   </script>
```

Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this Give zero to mindate and it will disable past dates.

```
   $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ minDate: 0});
```

or

```
var date = new Date();
var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(),date.getDate());

$('#date').datepicker({ 
minDate: today
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable future dates

```
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        maxDate: new Date
    });
```

Disable past dates

```
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    minDate: new Date
});
```